# Mapping strings in dataframe column to numerical values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, series

Good day all,

I need to change the characters in a string to a numerical value for a pandas series like so:

```
df = ['FF-FFF--FF+F-FFF',
     'F+-++--F+FF+-++-',
     'F++-FF-F-+F++-FF',
     'F+++++++++++++++',
     'F-F+-F-F+-F-F+-F',
     'F--F-+FFF+-FFF+-',
     'F+F-+F+F-+F+F-+F',
     'F--F--+-+++--F--',
     'F+FF--+FF--+FF--',
     'F-F+-+-F+-+-F+-+',
     'F++++-++++-++++-',
     'F+---++---++---+',
     'F+-+FF+-+FF+-+FF',
     'F+-FF-+-FF---+-F',
     'FF-+F+F-+F+F-+F+',
     'F+F+--+F+--+F+--',
     'FF+F-FFF---F+F-F',
     'FF+-FF-+---F+-FF',
     'F++--+++--+++--+']

num_dict = {'+':1, '-':2, 'F':3}

transformed_df = [3323332233132333,
                  3121122313312112,
                  3112332321311233,
                  3111111111111111,
                  3231232312323123,
                  3223213331233312,
                  3132131321313213,
                  3223221211122322,
                  3133221332213322,
                  3231212312123121,
                  3111121111211112,
                  3122211222112221,
                  3121331213312133,
                  3123321233222123,
                  3321313213132131,
                  3131221312213122,
                  3313233322231323,
                  3312332122231233,
                  3112211122111221]
```

I've tried [mapping](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the dataframe to the dictionary but that only considers the entire string not each character. Then I tried mapping the string to a tuple and then to the dictionary however this also did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by `dict.get()`:

```
s = pd.Series(df)
s.apply(lambda x: ''.join([str(num_dict.get(i)) for i in list(x)]))
```

---

```
0     3323332233132333
1     3121122313312112
2     3112332321311233
3     3111111111111111
4     3231232312323123
5     3223213331233312
6     3132131321313213
7     3223221211122322
8     3133221332213322
9     3231212312123121
10    3111121111211112
11    3122211222112221
12    3121331213312133
13    3123321233222123
14    3321313213132131
15    3131221312213122
16    3313233322231323
17    3312332122231233
18    3112211122111221
dtype: object
```

Note: if you want the numbers as numbers not as strings, you can later do `s=pd.to_numeric(s,errors='coerce')`

Comment: Excellent! Thank you

Comment: Is there a reverse for `dict.get()`?

Comment: Like say I want to reverse `3322332132` to `FF--FF-+F-`

Comment: @ZackJoubert reverse the dict `new_d={v:k for k,v in num_dict.items()}` and then `s.apply(lambda x: ''.join([new_d.get(int(i)) for i in list(x)]))`

Comment: nice listcomp and really fast. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re    
num_dict = {'+':1, '-':2, 'F':3} 
pattern = re.compile("("+"|".join(re.escape(i) for i in num_dict) + ")")

df = pd.DataFrame({"Col": data})
df["Col"] = df["Col"].apply(lambda x: pattern.sub(lambda y: str(num_dict[y.group(1)]), x))
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                 Col
0   3323332233132333
1   3121122313312112
2   3112332321311233
3   3111111111111111
4   3231232312323123
5   3223213331233312
6   3132131321313213
7   3223221211122322
8   3133221332213322
9   3231212312123121
10  3111121111211112
11  3122211222112221
12  3121331213312133
13  3123321233222123
14  3321313213132131
15  3131221312213122
16  3313233322231323
17  3312332122231233
18  3112211122111221
```

Answer (score 1):

**Fast**:

Use `str.replace` with callable

```
s.str.replace(r'\+|\-|F', lambda m: str(num_dict[m.group(0)]))
```

---

**Slow**:

Using `str.split` to expand to columns and `replace`, `agg` to join it back to string:

```
s.str.split('', expand=True).replace(num_dict).astype(str).agg(''.join, axis=1)

Out[296]:
0     3323332233132333
1     3121122313312112
2     3112332321311233
3     3111111111111111
4     3231232312323123
5     3223213331233312
6     3132131321313213
7     3223221211122322
8     3133221332213322
9     3231212312123121
10    3111121111211112
11    3122211222112221
12    3121331213312133
13    3123321233222123
14    3321313213132131
15    3131221312213122
16    3313233322231323
17    3312332122231233
18    3112211122111221
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the most elegant way, but it should work.
You could use Python's built-in replace() function.

This way you could run through the list and apply the replace() function for each char you want to replace.

```
df_transformed = []
for line in df:
  df_transformed.append(int(line.replace('F', '3').replace('-', '2').replace('+', '1')))
```

this way you would get the transformed dataframe as you described.

And sorry for the poor formatting. I typed this on my mobile phone, but I will edit it as soon as I got a computer avaliable.